# Best tool and approach to cut new hole for airbrick in Victorian stone house wall?

Tags: drill, brick, subfloor, stone

It has been recommended by a building surveyor that will install another airbrick in the external wall of our Victorian house to help with airflow in the sub floor.

I have seen multiple examples online of how to install a new airbrick on a modern brick house but not on a house made of stone where the stone are much harder and of uneven size. I wonder what the best tool for the job would be and the best approach to drill the rectangular space and correctly bed the airbrick?

[image]

Comment: Assuming (since I'm not familiar with the term) that an airbrick is a brick with air holes, I would think that simply drilling holes of whatever size those are directly in the wall would be much simpler than making a square hole to mortar a brick into.

Comment: Yes it is - most old houses with a subfloor have them installed. Not sure it would be recommended to just drill holes in the stonework but I might be wrong

Comment: @AWGIS It's not just old houses; it's required by code for any construction with a crawlspace foundation to be breathable in this manner. But there's nothing wrong with Ecnerwal's solution. It's way simpler and cheaper (assuming you have or can rent/borrow an appropriate drill & bit) to just 'convert' a normal brick into an airbrick. Just be sure to cover it with a grate on one or both sides so that critters don't use it as a door into a new spacious hotel :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I didn't really think of the option to just drill holes. In an ideal world I would prefer to fit a proper vent to be in keeping with the rest of the airbricks. I have also read examples where the drilled holes have slowly degraded or blocked themselves up with salt growth